# Custom properties and lambda expressions

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

I've added a custom property to a LINQ-to-SQL entity:

```
public partial class User
{
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get
        {
            // note that startDate and endDate are columns of User table
            return startDate <= DateTime.Now && endDate >= DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```

and now I need to use this property with lambda expressions:

```
activeUsers = users.Where(u => u.IsActive);
```

but when this code is executed I get a `System.NotSupportedException`. The exception message says that *"SQL conversions for the member 'User.IsActive' are not supported"*.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: What's "my logic"? There may be something causing it to fall over when it reads the property value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `IsActive` you show is regular C# - it will be compiled to IL and will not be available for LINQ-to-SQL (etc) to inspect and turn into TSQL to execute at the database. One option here might be:

```
public static Expression<Func<User,bool>> GetIsActiveFilter() {
    return user => user.StartDate <= DateTime.Now &&
                   user.EndDate >= DateTime.Now;
}
```

then you should be able to use:

```
activeUsers = users.Where(User.GetIsActiveFilter());
```

Or similarly - maybe an extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<User> ActiveOnly(this IQueryable<User> users) {
    return users.Where(user => user.StartDate <= DateTime.Now &&
                               user.EndDate >= DateTime.Now);
}
```

then:

```
activeUsers = users.ActiveOnly();
```

The difference here is that we are using the `IQueryable<T>` interface and *expression trees* throughout, which allows LINQ to understand our *intent*, and create suitable TSQL to achieve the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
activeUsers = users.AsEnumerable().Where(u => u.IsActive);
```

Note though that the criteria IsActive will not be translated to SQL since the logic behind IsActive is not known from a database perspective. So the database will execute a read on the whole table users, and the criteria will be applied in-memory.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my similar problem in this way:

my ORM was NHibernate and the underlying DB was Oracle, when i need to add some field like IsActive, did somthing like this

```
public partial class User
{
   public bool IsActive{get;set;}
}
```

in the related mapping file add something like this

```
<property name="IsActive" access="property" insert="false" update="false"
  formula="case when startDate  <= sysdate And endDate  >= sysdate then 1 else 0 end" />
```

now you can use

```
activeUsers = users.Where(u => u.IsActive);
```