# System.Linq.Expressions with computed column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In the MVC project I'm working I have a kendo dropDownList that calls my server Action to execute any read operation (including filtering):

```
ServiceRequestAssociabili([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int? idServiceRequestOriginale)
```

The widget is bound to 2 properties:
IdServiceRequest (value) and IdServiceRequestDescrizione(text).

IdServiceRequest is the Entity Id and IdServiceRequestDescrizione is a computed column which I have defined in the Partial class of the Entity

```
public string IdServiceRequestDescrizione
        {
            get
            {
                if (TipologiaChiamata.IdTipologiaChiamata != (int)Enums.TipologiaChiamata.Automatica)
                {
                    return IdServiceRequest + " " + Note;
                }
                else
                {
                    return IdServiceRequest + " " + Email.EmailOggetto;
                }
            }
        }
```

In order to create the correct linq query to execute the filter I created a System.Linq.Expression that translate my Entity to the DTO containing 2 string properties:

```
Expression<Func<ServiceRequest, DTO>> funcError = s => new DTO
            {
                IdServiceRequest = s.IdServiceRequest,
                IdServiceRequestDescrizione = s.IdServiceRequestDescrizione
            };
```

I then use this Expression to project my IQueryable:

```
var srq = _serviceRequestRepository.GetByParametersAsQueryable(idServiceRequestOriginale: idServiceRequestOriginale, senzaTicketAssociato: true).Select(funcError).ToList();
```

When I materialize the query with ToList() the following error occurs:

[image]

If I instead of defining IdServiceRequestDescrizione in the partial I define it inside the System.Linq.Expression no error is thrown and everything works fine.

```
Expression<Func<ServiceRequest, DTO>> func = s => new DTO
            {
                IdServiceRequest = s.IdServiceRequest,
                IdServiceRequestDescrizione = s.TipologiaChiamata.IdTipologiaChiamata != (int)EntityModel.Enums.TipologiaChiamata.Automatica ? s.IdServiceRequest + " " + s.Note : s.IdServiceRequest + " " + s.Email.EmailOggetto
            };
```

Can somebody give me a professional explanation of this behavior? Why I can't reference a custom property in the linq Expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computed column is implemented in C#, but EF only operates on the database model (translated to/from SQL).

Your code should work if you reverse the order of method calls to

```
.ToList().Select(funcError);
```

i.e. the records are first translated into C# entity objects, and then computed columns are accessible. (I usually use NHibernate, but the issue is the same)

Comment: Isn't linq.Expression implemented with c# as well? In my scenario I can't materialize the entities in that instruction because additional filters are applied to the Iqueryable object. To be clear: ToList() must be used after the projection to the DTO.

Comment: This question asks basically the same thing: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726285/custom-properties-and-lambda-expressions**

Answer (score 0):

There are some choices:

1) Linq.Tranlations [Linq.Tranlations](https://github.com/damieng/Linq.Translations)

Which allow you to write things like that:

```
public class Customer
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }

  private static readonly CompiledExpression<Customer, string> fullNameExpression
     = DefaultTranslationOf<Customer>.Property(e => e.FullName).Is(e => e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName);

  [NotMapped]
  public string FullName
  {
    get { return fullNameExpression.Evaluate(this); }
  }
}

var customers = ctx.Customers
  .Select(c => new
  {
    FullName = c.FullName
  })
  .WithTranslations();
```

2) DelegateDecompiler [DelegateDecompiler](https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler)

```
public class Customer
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }

  [NotMapped]
  [Computed]
  public string FullName
  {
    get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
  }
}
var customers = ctx.Customers
  .Select(c => new
  {
    FullName = c.FullName
  })
  .Decompile();
```